# How to set bar button item background image globally in iOS 13

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, ios13

iOS 13 has a whole new set of classes for configuring navigation bars and bar button items:

- UIBarAppearance
- UINavigationBarAppearance
- UIBarButtonItemAppearance
- UIBarButtonItemStateAppearance

How do I use these to give bar button items a global appearance? Let's say I want all bar button items to have a common background image. I used to say:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackgroundImage(im, for:.normal, barMetrics:.default)
```

This seems to be just what is superseded by these new classes. So what's the right way now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's verbose, but in some ways it's clearer. You can configure a navigation bar appearance and assign it to the navigation bar's `standardAppearance` through the proxy:

```
    let app = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    app.normal.backgroundImage = im
    let navbarapp = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navbarapp.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navbarapp.buttonAppearance = app
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navbarapp
```

The only problem with that is that it assigns the same background image to *back* button items. So if that's not desired, you have to code defensively, assigning back button items an empty (not `nil`) image:

```
    let app = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    app.normal.backgroundImage = im
    let navbarapp = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navbarapp.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navbarapp.buttonAppearance = app
    let back = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
    back.normal.backgroundImage = UIImage() // prevent back button item
    navbarapp.backButtonAppearance = back
    UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navbarapp
```